# Multithreaded Signalling

Tags: c++, windows, boost

I want to design a multithreaded application that does the following:
One thread writes sequentially to a circular buffer. Then there will be n-number of reader threads that wait on some signal initiated by the writer thread to wake up and read from the circular buffer. The signal should somehow contain an integer value that represents the circular buffer offset to read to. Is this possible to do in c++?
Any help would be appreciated.

Since I want a design that can process as near as possible high-speed, real time traffic, I want to eliminate any allocation/deallocation of memory. So the circular queue would be a contiguous chunk of memory allocated at startup. I am uncertain if the queuing you're referring to is in line with this.

The producer would only need to keep track of where to begin writing into the circular buffer array of bytes each time it has something to write.
So all I am really asking for is a way for the producer to disseminate a "signal" when it has completed a writing event that contains the location (offset) of the last byte written to in the circular buffer. This would avoid needing a locking mechanism.

The consumer threads will wake up when this "disseminated" signal/event is received. They, themselves, only need to keep keep track of where they've left off, then just read up until the signal offset value.
Finally, producer and consumers, of course need to know where the circular buffer begins and how big it is so they know when to wrap.

Comment: You should show us what you've tried and describe how its behavior deviates from your expectations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your most recent edit, I would suggest using a bounded queue.

A bounded queue is a queue with a specific length, so the queue is allocated in full at the beginning, and all the elements will simply be initialized based on the default constructor of the elements, or be null, whatever you want it to be.

From the producer side: If the queue is not full, push_back an element onto the queue.

From the consumer side: If the queue is not empty, pop an element off the queue and process it.

You do not need to send messages between your producers and consumers this way.  In fact, making your various threads communicate somehow will create a lot of overhead, which will only become more complicated with more threads.

The queue itself needs to be thread-safe, and there are examples on SO on how to make a thread safe bounded queue in C++.

**Edit:**

You can put anything you want in the queue.  I would suggest a queue of pointers in your case, because the size of a pointer will be constant throughout execution.  This allows you to allocate the queue up front, but means you have to allocate for your datagrams during run-time.

Your idea of thread-safe is more or less true.  In some cases, it's fine for multiple threads to access a single variable - usually when they are not modifying the variable, but just reading it.  Even if you're using a circular buffer, the circular buffer must also be thread-safe, because any two producers or consumers will make changes to the circular buffer.

That being said, the access time each thread needs to your circular buffer or queue will be extremely small - it should be enough time to copy information into or out of the data structure, and that's it.  All your other calculations with the data can be done without locking the data structure from other threads.

If you want multiple threads to access the data at once, you might want to think about creating multiple queues or buffers.  Perhaps one circular buffer per producer/consumer pair, or one queue per input stream...whatever it happens to be.  It's hard to say without a more concrete example.

**Edit 2**

[Here's a link to a thread-safe queue](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/implementing-a-thread-safe-queue-using-condition-variables.html).  I'm not sure if it'll help but it looks promising.

Comment: Can the items queued be of varying lengths ie datagrams? Also, from my understanding thread-safe means that only one thread can act on the queue at a time. What I am striving to with my approach, albeit a bit more complicated, doesn't have that limitation.

Comment: This last exchange has helped a lot. The bounded queue approach makes a lot of sense. Now I need to use a queue class that has a method that waits until the queue isn't empty. The one producer/one consumer model will work for me. I will not need to allocate the datagrams during run-time. At startup I just need to create a large contiguous block of memory and then stream the datagrams into it, wrap when I need to, etc. Each queued item will point to the next datagram in the circular buffer and them I can process the datagram in place. I can work out circ buff size thru trial and error.

Comment: @AlKurlansky I'm glad to help!  I recently did this in a similar scenario using boost::mutex and boost::condition_variable, but I can't seem to find the SO page that helped me.  I found another article that looks promising.  I'll add the link to my post.

Answer (score 3):

This is, IMO, a poor way to do things. Have the producer simply add items to the circular buffer. Have each reader wait on the circular buffer to be non-empty. When it's non-empty, the reader thread simply removes the next item from the buffer and processes it. The buffer itself should keep track of things like offsets.

As to why this is better: largely because it lets each part of the system do its own thing, with minimal interaction with other parts of the system.

As you're describing the system, the producer needs to know about the internal details of the queue, as well as essentially all the details of the consumer threads (which ones to wake at any given time, which are idle at any given time, which to schedule to carry out any particular task, etc.)

The design I'm suggesting minimizes keeps the producer devoted to producing. Its *only* knowledge of the rest of the system consists of one thing: how to put tasks into the queue once it produces them.

Likewise, the consumer threads only need to know how to get a task from the queue, and how to carry out that task.

The queue itself is responsible for all the required thread synchronization. Synchronization is only needed when a task gets put into/removed from the queue. The queue itself is quite reusable (can be used for nearly such producer-consumer situation) and replaceable (e.g., fairly trivial switching between lock-based and lock-free implementations).

The thread scheduling is left to the OS -- idle consumer threads simply wait on the queue, and the OS decides which one to wake to carry out a particular task. If none of them is currently idle, the OS already "knows" that too, and leaves them to do their current processing until one finishes and waits on the queue again.

Summary: what you've suggested makes each of the three parts of the system more complex. Worse, it intertwines the three, so it's difficult to work with any of those parts in isolation.

With this design, each part of the design remains substantially simpler, *and* each of them remains quite isolated from the others, so each can be worked with, reasoned about, etc., in isolation from the others.

Comment: If you're saying something is a poor way to do things, it would be beneficial if you backed that up with some explanation as to why you think so.